# Firebase Recycler Adapter set visibility of views in custom layout

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a project that uses Firebase UI's FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. So my problem is that a user can post a status update that gets stored in my data base as a unique post id containing child's (username,title,description,image). Everything is retrieved fine with no errors, but I want to make it so that a user can choose whether or not he/she wants to add an image.

So in my `populateViewHolder` method, if I use

```
if(model.getImage() != null){
    viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage())
}else{
    viewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

some images won't show even when they should.

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: When I do this some images won't show even if there url is not null.